# Understanding critical points of trig functions better

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am having trouble understanding the following function and critical points along with min/max of trig functions, any help is greatly appreciated.

Let's say we have $f(x) = \frac x2 + sin(x)$

then: $f'(x) = \frac 12 + cos(x)$

Set $f'(x) = 0$ and we get $cos(x) = -\frac12$

That's where I get lost. I have no idea how to change that into $\frac {2\pi} 3$ but I know that's a critical point, I just have no idea how to get there from $cos(x) = - \frac 12$ --- What if cos(x) = 1? How would I have solved those critical points?

After that, I have no idea how to get to the min/max. If there's no trig, no problem, I can get the relative extrema (relative min/max) and plug critical points and tests back into the original function.

It's been about 10 years since I've taken pre-calc and I'm in Calc 1 now after going back to school. All of the unit circle and that kind of stuff is lost on me. If anyone can suggest a good method to understanding that I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much.

Comment: This [short video from khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:trig/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:unit-circle/v/unit-circle-definition-of-trig-functions-1) will help you solve trig equations like the ones in your question

Comment: I've used khan academy A LOT, but every video on this topic that I've found is like "here's how we find a critical point f(x) = 1/2sin^2(x) + cos(2x) and I can do derivative fine, I can get all the way to setting it equal to zero and get where they get, then the video is like "well we know that *whatever the value set to zero* is equal to "pi/2" but I can't find where the explain that exact spot / video describing that EXACT part that I just can't grasp / remember. I don't even know what that "change" is called to google it.

I appreciate the input.

Comment: You edited it after I finished replying haha, going to check that video out now, thank you for sending me to a specific video.

Comment: Good luck! Khan is great at teaching these fundamentals... but feel free to get back if something isn't clear

Comment: Alright, so I've watched it and it refreshed me a bit. Let me see if I'm making sense of this.

Comment: Nice. If I may, some free advice from my own experience - when you sit to study, don't force yourself to learn everything at once.  Take deep breaths every few minutes and recall encouraging facts like, you didn't learn to walk on the same day you were born, etc. These take time and if you rush you will definitely waste more time than necessary.

Comment: Sorry, stack exchange wouldn't let me edit, and I hit enter on accident lol.

So...

Cos(x) = - 1/2
the original problem had the domain of (0,2pi) or a unit circle. Cos(anything) is really just saying that the X value is that, or -1/2 it seems, so looking AT the unit circle if the x value is -1/2 you get 2pi/3 and 4pi/3. 

If the derivative was say... sin(x) = -1/2 then a critical point would be 11pi/6, right?

So I get that I think. Is there any easy way to remember all of those points on the unit circle or how do I find those pi values easily?

Comment: Also, I wish someone had told me that like 10 years ago. Lol.

That's such a good point on studying, especially in the math world (I'm also in the comp sci world, so there too). I think life(society) tends to teach you that "learning" is being able to answer problems quickly, when that's really understanding, learning is the struggle to solve the problem.

Comment: You have to memorize only $5$ values in entire trig: $$0, 1/2, 1/\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}/2, 1$$. 

everything else can be cooked up from above. Do you remember the [trig table](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ucDa1O5w_zQ/maxresdefault.jpg)?

Comment: For example. Knowing $\cos(\pi/3) = 1/2$ you can find the value of $\cos(2\pi/3)$. Do you know how ?

Comment: [Here](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ISFyyiHaUlg/maxresdefault.jpg) is a hint

Comment: I think because cos(x) = -sin(x) so the sin of 60 degrees is the y value of sin of 60 or sqrt(3)/2

I don't do well with the changing from degrees to radians. I can do the degrees.

Let's say the derivative of a function after solving for it equal to zero is sin(x) = 1/2

I know I can look at the unit circle and see that when the Y value is 1/2 the radians answer is 7pi/6 or pi/6 but I don't know how to get that without looking at the unit circle.

Comment: cos(x) = -sin(x) is not true

Comment: I too prefer degrees. Using unit circle is fine. Infact it is recommended :)

Comment: Yeah, I got that backwards, lol. 

how can I do it without the unit circle? That's my biggest struggle right now. during a test I would not be able to get cos(x) = -1/2 and know that a critical point is 2pi/3. I'm not sure what I can memorize other than the unit circle to know how to solve that.

Comment: There is a nice trick. Since $\cos(\theta) $ is the $x$ coordinate on unit circle, can you see why below is true? $$\cos(\theta) = -\cos(180-\theta)$$

Comment: $$\cos(120) = -\cos(180-120) = -\cos(60) = ?$$

Comment: So, if I get the derivative of a function and it's Cos(x) = 1. I can memorize that cos(1) = 0. From there, -cos(180-x) - the reference angle is -cos(180), which I can memorize as pi. -cos(x) where x = 1 is ALSO pi.

So in the example you gave, cos(120), then -cos(60) is -1/2 or -pi/3 right?

So in the example you gave earlier if I get cos(x) = 1/2, I know -cos(180-x) = -cos(120) or -1/2

Comment: Also because SIN, the y value, IS -cos(x) right?

Comment: Take a break! Perhaps this is easy to remember:  $$\cos(\pi-x) = -\cos(x)$$. Plugin $x = \pi/3$

Comment: I'll summarize:  Since you want to know when $\cos(\theta)$ equals $-1/2$, it is a good idea to first recall that $\cos(\theta)$ equals $1/2$ when $\theta= \pi/3$. Next recall the identity $\cos(\pi-\theta) = -\cos(\theta)$ to conclude that $\cos(\theta) = -1/2$when $\theta = \pi-\pi/3 = 2\pi/3$

Comment: That last part is extremely helpful. Thank you so much for taking the time to help with that.

I think part of my problem is not only that I don't remember the trig table, but the identity of cos(x) = -cos(x), is there a table that shows those with Sin, tan etc that I can also look over? I think having that understanding will help a lot.

Comment: You can google the identities, but a more reliable way is to just remember one thing: $\cos(\theta)$ is the $x$ coordinate on unit circle. Then using this, you can work TWO useful identities: $$\cos(-\theta) = \cos(\theta)$$  $$\cos(180-\theta) =- \cos(\theta)$$

Comment: To work the first identity, stare at [this picture](http://www.analyzemath.com/high_school_math/grade_11/trigo/unit_circle_negative.gif). What do you notice about the $x$ coordinate for the points $A$ and $D$ ?

Comment: [Here](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/trigonometricratiosandidentities-130406033612-phpapp02/95/trigonometric-ratios-and-identities-5-638.jpg?cb=1365219430) is a list of identites, but nobody memorizes these. You must be able to work these based on unit circle definition. That is $\sin(\theta)$ = `x` coordinate  and $\cos(\theta)$ = `y` coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

$cos(x)$ = $-1/2$
If you take inverse of cosine on both sides you end up with $x$ = $2\pi/3$
In the case of $cos(x) = 1$, the solution would be $x = 2\pi n$ where $n \in {0,1,2,.....}$

I am not sure what do you mean by $min$ and $max$ here.
I assume in a closed ranged say $(-\pi, \pi)$ the minimum and maximum value of x in the range.
For $cos(x) = -1/2$ the min and max values would be $-2\pi /3$  and  $2\pi /3$. Same for the case of $cos(x) = 1$ you find only one value in range of $(-\pi, \pi)$ that is $0$.

Comment: I've updated my original post, I meant relative extrema and the range was (0,2pi).

I don't understand what you mean by the "inverse of cosine on both sides" do you mean just the x-value? As someone pointed out above I realize now that cos(x) really is just the x value.

Comment: @airhoodz I would recommend that you go through some tutorials to understand the trigonometric functions